# Multiple times Screen render on API call in react native

Tags: react-native

I have put console log inside of my functional component file. In this file render whenever the API called. If I called API in some other file and the API not related to that file still got logs. I am not sure why. I have checked useEffect and usestate but no clue. Even search from google no clue.

1. I am using Usestate to store and useEffect to reloaded the the page when data change
2. I am using apisauce to call the API
3. React native navigation bottomtab to navigate the screen
4. Using React.memo but still page rendered.

Any one please help me to resolve this issue. because I am new to react native.

Comment: why dont you try class component ?

Comment: That's not possible right now. because I almost done and function component was easy for me. also how could I resolve by using class component. @Dipan Sharma

Answer (score 0):

React components automatically re-render whenever there is a change in their state or props. A simple update of the state, from anywhere in the code, causes all the User Interface (UI) elements to be re-rendered automatically.

However, there may be cases where the render() method depends on some other data. After the initial mounting of components, a re-render will occur when:

A component’s setState() method is called.

A component’s forceUpdate() method is called.

**Warning**: You should normally try to avoid all uses of forceUpdate() and only read from this.props and this.state in render().

Comment: Thanks for your response @Mehroze Yaqoob. How can I avoid this issue in react native ?. can you please help me.

Comment: This is not an issue, its the way react native performs invalidation on UI. If you believe too much re-rendering is causing jerkness to your screen then you need to apply appropriate if-else checks to avoid re-rendering.